# Chrome and IE do not show tag values from XML file

Tags: javascript, html, xml, internet-explorer, google-chrome

I have following HTML code:

```
<html>
<body>
<h1>W3Schools Internal Note</h1>
<div>
 <b>To:</b> <span id="to"></span><br />
<b>From:</b> <span id="from"></span><br />
<b>Message:</b> <span id="message"></span>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
   xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
 }
else
 {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.open("GET","languages.xml",false);
xmlhttp.send();
xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML;

document.getElementById("to").innerHTML=
 xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("to")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
document.getElementById("from").innerHTML=
xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("from")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
document.getElementById("message").innerHTML=
xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

This code works in Firefox but not working in Chrome and IE. I mean Firefox shows the results of XML tags from XML document but Chrome and IE are not!!!
Please help me out.

Comment: 1) Synchronous AJAX calls are a bad idea. 2) stop using w3schools: http://www.w3fools.com

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing `nodeValue` with `textContent` on all of your elements.  If this is not the solution please post your XML.